# Hydraulic network works with StaticPipe but not with DynamicPipe in OpenModelica

Tags: fluid, modelica, dymola, openmodelica

As mentioned in the title, I'm trying to model an hydraulic network. It is working properly when I use the `StaticPipe` of the `ModelicaStandardLibrary`. However, as I'll need to introduce heat transfer later on, I tried to make the same model but using DynamicPipe instead. As it is mentioned in the documentation of the `StaticPipe`, it is equivalent to the `DynamicPipe` with `SteadyState` settings. As I don't consider heat transfers yet, I replaced every `StaticPipe` with `DynamicPipe` in SteadyState and I disabled the `use_heattransfer` option. The model is balanced, however when I launch the simulation I get the following error message and the simulation runs indefinitely. I have to cancel it.

[image]

Here is the code I use :

```
    model Circuit_hydraulique_21_03

  replaceable package Medium=Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater constrainedby
    Modelica.Media.Interfaces.PartialMedium;

  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT inlet(redeclare package Medium = Medium,T = 311.15, p = 4.4e5, nPorts = 1)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-588, -2}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  //steady state definition
  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system(energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyState, massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyState, momentumDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.SteadyState)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-588, 88}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T boundary(redeclare package Medium = Medium,T = 311.15, m_flow = -2.5, nPorts = 1)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {434, 0}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe entree(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 42.7e-3, length = 10, nNodes = 10, roughness = 3.2e-06, use_HeatTransfer = false)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-558, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.AbruptAdaptor abruptAdaptor(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter_a = 42.7e-3, diameter_b = 32e-3) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-534, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe entree_Primary(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 32e-3, length = 185e-3, roughness = 3.2e-06, use_HeatTransfer = false)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-508, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.AbruptAdaptor abruptAdaptor1(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter_a = 32e-3, diameter_b = 38e-3) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-482, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_1(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-456, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_2(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-426, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_3(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-398, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_4(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-368, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_5(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-338, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_6(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-310, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_7(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-282, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_8(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-254, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_9(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-226, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_10(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-196, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_12(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-136, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Secondary_1(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 12.8e-3, length = 15633e-3, roughness = 3.2e-06, use_HeatTransfer = false)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-442, -34}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Secondary_2(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 12.8e-3, length = 15633e-3, roughness = 3.2e-06, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-414, -34}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Secondary_3(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 12.8e-3, length = 15633e-3, roughness = 3.2e-06, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-384, -34}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Secondary_4(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 12.8e-3, length = 15633e-3, roughness = 3.2e-06, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-354, -34}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Secondary_5(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 12.8e-3, length = 15633e-3, roughness = 3.2e-06, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-324, -34}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Secondary_6(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 12.8e-3, length = 15633e-3, roughness = 3.2e-06, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-296, -34}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Secondary_7(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 12.8e-3, length = 15633e-3, roughness = 3.2e-06, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-268, -34}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Secondary_8(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 12.8e-3, length = 15633e-3, roughness = 3.2e-06, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-242, -34}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Secondary_9(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 12.8e-3, length = 15633e-3, roughness = 3.2e-06, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-212, -34}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Secondary_10(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 12.8e-3, length = 15633e-3, roughness = 3.2e-06, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-182, -34}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Secondary_11(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 12.8e-3, length = 15633e-3, roughness = 3.2e-06, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-152, -34}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Secondary_12(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 12.8e-3, length = 15633e-3, roughness = 3.2e-06, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-120, -34}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = -90)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_11(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-166, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_13(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-94, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_14(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-64, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_15(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-32, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_16(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-2, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_17(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {28, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_18(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {58, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_19(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {90, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_20(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {124, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_21(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {158, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_22(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38
e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {192, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_23(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {224, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Primary_24(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 38e-3, length = 24.532e-3, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {258, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.AbruptAdaptor abruptAdaptor2(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter_a = 38e-3, diameter_b = 32e-3) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {288, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe sortie_Primary(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 32e-3, length = 185e-3, roughness = 3.2e-06, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {318, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.AbruptAdaptor abruptAdaptor3(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter_a = 32e-3, diameter_b = 42.7e-3) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {348, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe sortie(redeclare package Medium = Medium,diameter = 42.7e-3, length = 10, nNodes = 10, roughness = 3.2e-06, use_HeatTransfer = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {384, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));

equation
  connect(entree.port_b, abruptAdaptor.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-548, 0}, {-544, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(entree.port_b, abruptAdaptor.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-548, 0}, {-544, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(abruptAdaptor.port_b, entree_Primary.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-524, 0}, {-518, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(entree_Primary.port_b, abruptAdaptor1.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-498, 0}, {-492, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(abruptAdaptor1.port_b, Primary_1.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-472, 0}, {-466, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_1.port_b, Primary_2.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-446, 0}, {-436, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_2.port_b, Primary_3.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-416, 0}, {-408, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_3.port_b, Primary_4.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-388, 0}, {-378, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_4.port_b, Primary_5.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-358, 0}, {-348, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_5.port_b, Primary_6.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-328, 0}, {-320, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_6.port_b, Primary_7.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-300, 0}, {-292, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_7.port_b, Primary_8.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-272, 0}, {-264, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_8.port_b, Primary_9.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-244, 0}, {-236, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_9.port_b, Primary_10.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-216, 0}, {-206, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_1.port_b, Secondary_1.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-446, 0}, {-442, 0}, {-442, -24}, {-442, -24}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_2.port_b, Secondary_2.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-416, 0}, {-414, 0}, {-414, -24}, {-414, -24}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_3.port_b, Secondary_3.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-388, 0}, {-384, 0}, {-384, -24}, {-384, -24}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_4.port_b, Secondary_4.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-358, 0}, {-354, 0}, {-354, -24}, {-354, -24}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_5.port_b, Secondary_5.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-328, 0}, {-324, 0}, {-324, -24}, {-324, -24}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_6.port_b, Secondary_6.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-300, 0}, {-296, 0}, {-296, -24}, {-296, -24}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_7.port_b, Secondary_7.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-272, 0}, {-268, 0}, {-268, -24}, {-268, -24}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_8.port_b, Secondary_8.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-244, 0}, {-242, 0}, {-242, -24}, {-242, -24}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_9.port_b, Secondary_9.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-216, 0}, {-212, 0}, {-212, -24}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_10.port_b, Secondary_10.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-186, 0}, {-182, 0}, {-182, -24}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_11.port_b, Primary_12.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-156, 0}, {-146, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_10.port_b, Primary_11.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-186, 0}, {-176, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_11.port_b, Secondary_11.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-156, 0}, {-152, 0}, {-152, -24}, {-152, -24}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_12.port_b, Secondary_12.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-126, 0}, {-120, 0}, {-120, -24}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Secondary_12.port_b, Primary_13.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-120, -44}, {-120, -44}, {-120, -50}, {-108, -50}, {-108, 0}, {-104, 0}, {-104, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_13.port_b, Primary_14.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-84, 0}, {-74, 0}, {-74, 0}, {-74, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_14.port_b, Primary_15.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-54, 0}, {-42, 0}, {-42, 0}, {-42, 0}, {-42, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_15.port_b, Primary_16.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-22, 0}, {-12, 0}, {-12, 0}, {-12, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_16.port_b, Primary_17.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{8, 0}, {16, 0}, {16, 0}, {18, 0}, {18, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_17.port_b, Primary_18.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{38, 0}, {46, 0}, {46, 0}, {48, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_18.port_b, Primary_19.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{68, 0}, {80, 0}, {80, 0}, {80, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_19.port_b, Primary_20.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{100, 0}, {110, 0}, {110, 0}, {114, 0}, {114, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_20.port_b, Primary_21.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{134, 0}, {148, 0}, {148, 0}, {148, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_21.port_b, Primary_22.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{168, 0}, {182, 0}, {182, 0}, {182, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_22.port_b, Primary_23.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{202, 0}, {214, 0}, {214, 0}, {214, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_23.port_b, Primary_24.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{234, 0}, {248, 0}, {248, 0}, {248, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Secondary_11.port_b, Primary_14.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-152, -44}, {-154, -44}, {-154, -54}, {-78, -54}, {-78, 0}, {-74, 0}, {-74, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Secondary_10.port_b, Primary_15.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-182, -44}, {-182, -44}, {-182, -58}, {-48, -58}, {-48, 0}, {-42, 0}, {-42, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Secondary_9.port_b, Primary_16.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-212, -44}, {-212, -44}, {-212, -60}, {-12, -60}, {-12, 0}, {-12, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Secondary_8.port_b, Primary_17.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-242, -44}, {-242, -44}, {-242, -62}, {18, -62}, {18, 0}, {18, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Secondary_7.port_b, Primary_18.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-268, -44}, {-266, -44}, {-266, -64}, {48, -64}, {48, 0}, {48, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Secondary_6.port_b, Primary_19.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-296, -44}, {-296, -44}, {-296, -70}, {80, -70}, {80, 0}, {80, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Secondary_5.port_b, Primary_20.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-324, -44}, {-324, -44}, {-324, -72}, {114, -72}, {114, 0}, {114, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Secondary_4.port_b, Primary_21.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-354, -44}, {-356, -44}, {-356, -74}, {146, -74}, {146, 0}, {148, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Secondary_3.port_b, Primary_22.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-384, -44}, {-380, -44}, {-380, -76}, {182, -76}, {182, 0}, {182, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Secondary_2.port_b, Primary_23.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-414, -44}, {-414, -44}, {-414, -82}, {212, -82}, {212, 0}, {214, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Secondary_1.port_b, Primary_24.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-442, -44}, {-440, -44}, {-440, -88}, {248, -88}, {248, 0}, {248, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(Primary_24.port_b, abruptAdaptor2.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{268, 0}, {278, 0}, {278, 0}, {278, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(abruptAdaptor2.port_b, sortie_Primary.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{298, 0}, {308, 0}, {308, 0}, {308, 0}, {308, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(sortie_Primary.port_b, abruptAdaptor3.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{328, 0}, {338, 0}, {338, 0}, {338, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(abruptAdaptor3.port_b, sortie.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{358, 0}, {372, 0}, {372, 0}, {374, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(sortie.port_b, boundary.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{394, 0}, {424, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(inlet.ports[1], entree.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-578, -2}, {-578, 0}, {-568, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "3.2.3")),
    Diagram(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-600, -100}, {450, 100}}, initialScale = 0.1), graphics = {Ellipse(origin = {-119, -36}, extent = {{-1, -8}, {1, 8}}, endAngle = 360)}),
    Icon(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-600, -100}, {450, 100}})),
    version = "");
end Circuit_hydraulique_21_03;
```

Does anyone know why it's not working ?

Best regards,
Maxime

Comment: You should consider narrowing down your problem (model) and testing it on less than 40 instances of `DynamicPipe`. Then it will be easier for you to compare the two pipe models. By the way, your model does run in Dymola.

Comment: Thanks, I did as you suggest and it worked. Do you have any idea why the previous model did not run on openmodelica ? Is it due to an error in the model or was the model too complex ?

Comment: you could increase the number of pipes one by one in OpenModelica and see what happens. To me it looks like a problem with the solver e.g. the system might be too big. Other start values might also help. Or you could change the boundary conditions to one mass flow source and one pressure boundary.